# MongoDB background Index size

Tags: mongodb

I am creating an index ( { a : 1, b : -1 }), once foreground and other doing on background. Check the total index size.
Foreground : 82536720
Background : 154927024

Can someone tell me why there is a huge size difference ?

```
Mongo > db.testing.ensureIndex({a:1,b:-1})
Mongo > db.testing.stats()
{
    "ns" : "test.testing",
    "count" : 2402158,
    "size" : 86479836,
    "avgObjSize" : 36.00089419596879,
    "totalIndexSize" : 160486704,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 77949984,
        "a_1_b_-1" : 82536720
    },
}
Mongo > db.testing.dropIndexes()
Mongo > db.testing.ensureIndex({a:1,b:-1},{background : true})
Mongo > db.testing.stats()
{
    "count" : 2402158,
    "size" : 86479836,
    "avgObjSize" : 36.00089419596879,
    "totalIndexSize" : 232877008,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 77949984,
        "a_1_b_-1" : 154927024
    },
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the background index finished building before you checked its size?

Comment: @JohnnyHK : yes, I checked the db.currentOp() which was empty

Answer (score 5):

The [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/) says

> Background index construction allows read and write operations to continue while building the index; however, these index builds take longer to complete and result in a larger index.

So, no surprise.  Basically, mongo uses a different mechanism to build a background index than it does a foreground index, which, among other things, causes the final index to be larger.